# Jaxb unmarshalling error in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have created java classes in netbeans using jaxbbinding with an xsd.I creates 3 classes under a package called "Generated sources(jaxb)" within which there is a package called generated.I have created a class for unmarshalling in which i have imported generated.*; but it shows an error

```
error: package generated does not exist

      import generated.*;
```

at runtime.Though there is no error shown during compile time.